# Cannot insert image into Google Slides using app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides

I am trying to insert an image into a Google Slide using an App script. I have:

```
  SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().insertImage('');
```

I get error `insertPicture (Code:18)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Review the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide) for inserting images.

First off, `insertImage` must be called on a specific slide, not a specific presentation. It needs to know where to put the image.

Secondly, the content of insertImage can't be empty like that. It needs to be a url, blob, etc.

For example, try some code like this:

```js
var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0];
slide.insertImage('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Wiki_Eagle_Public_Domain.png');
```